# Ideas to improve SAS SQL query

Tags: sql, sas

This is based on a question I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41730377/how-to-count-distinct-id-in-the-last-90-days-on-sas/41733069) about how to use SAS to solve the following problem. [NOTE: There is a working SAS data step solution, but I was just trying to see how it would work in SQL.]

The problem (a little hard to describe) is to look at each transaction for a customer, look back 90 days from that transaction's date, count the total number of the customer's transactions in that 90-day window, save that number with the original transaction, count the number of distinct account managers handling the customer's transactions in that 90-day window, and save that number with the original transaction.

Here is the data step to initialize a test transaction dataset and my SAS SQL solution:

```
data transaction;
    length customerid $ 12 accountmanager $7 transactionid $ 12;
    input CustomerID AccountManager TransactionID Transaction_Time datetime.;
    format transaction_time datetime.;
    datalines;
1111111111  FA001          TR2016001      08SEP16:11:19:25
1111111111  FA001          TR2016002      26OCT16:08:22:49
1111111111  FA002          TR2016003      04NOV16:08:05:36
1111111111  FA003          TR2016004      04NOV16:17:15:52
1111111111  FA004          TR2016005      25NOV16:13:04:16
1231231234  FA005          TR2016006      25AUG15:08:03:29
1231231234  FA005          TR2016007      16SEP15:08:24:24
1231231234  FA008          TR2016008      18SEP15:14:42:29
;;;;
run;

proc sql;
    create table want as
        select mgrs.*, trans.tranct
        from
            (select t3.customerid, t3.accountmanager, t3.transactionid, t3.transaction_time, count(*) as mgrct
                from (select distinct t1.*, t2.accountmanager as m2
                      from transaction t1, transaction t2
                      where t1.customerid=t2.customerid
                            and
                          datepart(t1.transaction_time) >= datepart(t2.transaction_time)-90
                            and
                          t2.transaction_time <= t1.transaction_time) t3
                group by t3.customerid, t3.accountmanager, t3.transactionid, t3.transaction_time) mgrs,
            (select t4.customerid, t4.transactionid, count(*) as tranct
                from transaction t4, transaction t5
                where t4.customerid=t5.customerid
                        and
                      datepart(t4.transaction_time) >= datepart(t5.transaction_time)-90
                        and
                      t5.transaction_time <= t4.transaction_time
                group by t4.customerid, t4.transactionid) trans
        where mgrs.customerid=trans.customerid and mgrs.transactionid=trans.transactionid;
quit;
```

The result looks like this:

> ```
> customerid  accountmanager transactionid  Transaction_Time mgrct tranct
> 1111111111  FA001          TR2016001      08SEP16:11:19:25   1     1 
> 1111111111  FA001          TR2016002      26OCT16:08:22:49   1     2
> 1111111111  FA002          TR2016003      04NOV16:08:05:36   2     3
> 1111111111  FA003          TR2016004      04NOV16:17:15:52   3     4
> 1111111111  FA004          TR2016005      25NOV16:13:04:16   4     5
> 1231231234  FA005          TR2016006      25AUG15:08:03:29   1     1
> 1231231234  FA005          TR2016007      16SEP15:08:24:24   1     2
> 1231231234  FA008          TR2016008      18SEP15:14:42:29   2     3
> ```

I haven't used SQL for a long time, so I would like to know if there is a more elegant SQL solution. I thought it would be simpler, but actually the SAS data step code seems simpler than this SQL query.

Comment: You specifically want to work in this in SQL, or are you okay with the data step code?  I agree that it's likely SQL will be more complex than data step for this kind of issue.

Comment: @Joe - The original problem was someone else's, and I offered them a SAS data step solution. I was just curious how it would work in SQL, and this is what I came up with. So now I'm curious whether there is a more elegant SQL solution.

Comment: And you want SAS SQL solution specifically, right?  Not one that would work in most other SQL flavors but not the basic SAS one (i.e., using windowing functions)...

Comment: @Joe - I'm coming out of a long hiatus with SAS and SQL, so I'm not sure what you meant by "windowing functions." But I would be happy with SQL that would work in "standard" SQL or in SAS SQL. I see that Tom has come up with a much more compact query.

Comment: SAS implements something close to standard SQL. But sql server, oracle, etc. all have implemented windowing functions meant to do things like this easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need to join the table with itself.

```
proc sql noprint ;
 create table want as
   select a.*
        , count(distinct b.accountmanager) as mgrct
        , count(*) as tranct
   from transaction a
   left join transaction b
   on a.customerid = b.customerid
    and b.transaction_time <= a.transaction_time
    and datepart(a.transaction_time)-datepart(b.transaction_time)
        between 0 and 90
   group by 1,2,3,4
 ;
quit;
```

Results

```
1111111111 FA001 TR2016001 08SEP16:11:19:25 1 1  
1111111111 FA001 TR2016002 26OCT16:08:22:49 1 2  
1111111111 FA002 TR2016003 04NOV16:08:05:36 2 3  
1111111111 FA003 TR2016004 04NOV16:17:15:52 3 4  
1111111111 FA004 TR2016005 25NOV16:13:04:16 4 5  
1231231234 FA005 TR2016006 25AUG15:08:03:29 1 1  
1231231234 FA005 TR2016007 16SEP15:08:24:24 1 2  
1231231234 FA008 TR2016008 18SEP15:14:42:29 2 3
```

Comment: Thanks, Tom! What I was missing was `count(distinct b.accountmanager)`--my query went all over the place to duplicate that. Also, your query is much faster, at least for the test set of transactions.

Comment: Don't need the middle criteria if you implement the 0-90 using intck instead of datepart.

Comment: Looking back at this, I wonder why you used a left join. It seems like it works with a regular inner join because the transaction "of focus" always matches itself--there is always at least one row returned from "a" and "b".

Comment: Habit?  Since the output desired was to produce counts for every record in the original list that looked to me like a left join.  As long as the count includes the current observation in addition to the previous ones then inner join would work the same as a left join since that guarantees there will always be at least one match from the "right" table.